# How to make wget to save with proper file name

Tags: wget

When I went to the ISC [here](https://www.isc.org/downloads/) to download BIND, my browser automatically saves the downloaded file correctly.  For example, if I click on the Download button for 9.9.4-P2, it pops up a window, and if I click on the "BIND 9.9.4-P2 - tar.gz" button on the right the browser automatically saves the downloaded file as "bind-9.9.4-P2.tar.gz".

However what I'm trying to do is to download it via wget on Linux.  So I right click on the "BIND 9.9.4-P2 - tar.gz" button and copied the link which is "https://www.isc.org/downloads/file/bind-9-9-4-p1-tar-gz/?version=tar.gz".

Now when I then issued the following command, it'd save it as 'index.html?version=tar.gz' instead.  Now I understand I can give it the -O option and explicitly specify the saved file name but is there a way for it to do this automatically similar to how my browser does it?

```
wget https://www.isc.org/downloads/file/bind-9-9-4-p1-tar-gz/?version=tar.gz
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On an HTTP level, the server sends the filename information to the client in the `Content-Disposition` header field within the HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[…]
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="bind-9.9.4-P2.tar.gz";
```

See [RFC2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183%20RFC2183) for details on the `Content-Disposition` header field.

`wget` has experimental support for this feature according to its manpage:

> ```
>    --content-disposition
>       If this is set to on, experimental (not fully-functional) support for
>       "Content-Disposition" headers is enabled. This can currently result in
>       extra round-trips to the server for a "HEAD" request, and is known to
>       suffer from a few bugs, which is why it is not currently enabled by
>       default.
> ```

So if you choose to enable it, just specify the `--content-disposition` option. (You could also use `curl` to do the job instead of `wget`, but the question was about `wget`.)

Comment: You rock!  I tried using curl first but realized it doesn't work and saw somewhere I need a recent version of it (ie 7.21.2 or later).  This is surprising as looks like I only have Curl 7.19.0 installed with the the latest CentOS release 6.5 (Final)!  I tried using wget again with the --content-disposition and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 9):

You could set the content-disposition parameter to be activated by default.

Just edit the `/etc/wgetrc` or `~/.wgetrc` file and append `content-disposition = on`